# Modify layers in resnet model

Tags: keras, resnet

I am trying to train resnet50 model for image classification problem. I have loaded the pretrained 'imagenet' weights before training the model on the dataset I have. I want to insert a layer (mean subtraction layer) in-between the input layer and the first convolutiuon layer.

```python
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
def mean_subtract(img):
    img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,0,:,:],img[:,0,:,:] - 123.68)
    img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,1,:,:],img[:,1,:,:] - 116.779)
    img = T.set_subtensor(img[:,2,:,:],img[:,2,:,:] - 103.939)

    return img / 255.0
```

I want to insert `inputs = Lambda(mean_subtract, name='mean_subtraction')(inputs)` next to the input layer and connect this to the first convolution layer of resnet model without losing the weights saved.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer** (Seems better than adding the function to the model)

Use the preprocessing function as described here: [preprocessing images generated using keras function ImageDataGenerator() to train resnet50 model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133385/preprocessing-images-generated-using-keras-function-imagedatagenerator-to-trai/50136397#50136397)

**Long answer**

Since your function doesn't change shapes, you can put it in an outer model without changing the Resnet model (changing models may not be so simple, I always try to mount new models with parts from other models if needed).

```
resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

inputs = Input((None,None,3)) 
    #it seems you're using (3,None,None) instead.    
    #choose based on your "data_format", which by default is channels_last 

outputs = Lambda(mean_subtract,output_shape=not_necessary_with_tensorflow)(inputs)
outputs = resnet_model(outputs)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```