# Using particular size for the image in Keras resNet50

Tags: keras

I am trying to use RestNet50 (keras). I want to execute it with several images 
 of varying sizes since the default size of ResNet50 is 224x244. I have tried to change the argument `include_top` to `False` but it still does not work.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so the problem can be reproduced. Please also include you full error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preprocessing function included in applications.resnet50 as described here: [preprocessing images generated using keras function ImageDataGenerator() to train resnet50 model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50136397/2723405)

This will generate images form your inputs that are compatible with  ResNet50

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory, batch_size, shuffle=True, target_size, class_mode)
```

Comment: thank you for that, but what i want is " using include_top= False, so i can specify my input image not for training but got identifying. for example using input shape 200,200, 3 rather than the default (e.g. 224,224,3).